# F#: Approach to Trigrams

Tags: f#

I have a string "ABCDEFG".  I want to convert that into a string array with the contents: [|"ABC"; "BCD"; "CDE"; "DEF"; "EFG"|]

I first thought about using a loop.  Then I thought about using a recursive function.  Finally, I was wondering if there is a function in the F# spec like Seq.Fold I can use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [Seq.windowed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340420.aspx), should do what you want.

```
> "ABCDEFG" |> Seq.windowed 3 |> Seq.map (fun a -> System.String a);;
val it : seq<System.String> = seq ["ABC"; "BCD"; "CDE"; "DEF"; ...]
```

Comment: Great call Matt - Thanks!